# Can an OpenAL source ever be 0?

Tags: c++, openal

Can an OpenAL source generated by `alGenSources()` ever be `0`?

Because I would like to store `NULL` as source whenever the source has stopped playing.

It is stored as an `ALuint`.

I couldn't find it in the Programmers guide.

Comment: I think it would output `0` if unable to create the source.

Comment: Ah, then my plan would need to change a little :)

Comment: As `ALuint` is not a pointer type, your question would be better if it didn't use the `NULL` constant and asked, instead, if `0` is a valid source name.

Comment: Sure, but the question is still valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot rely on `0` being reserved as invalid, as it is allowed id by specs (up to implementation to decide).

According to [OpenAL 1.1 specs](https://www.openal.org/documentation/openal-1.1-specification.pdf):

> *2.12. Requesting Object Names*
>
> OpenAL provides calls to obtain object names.
> The application requests a number of objects of a given category using `alGen{Object}s`. The actual values of the names returned are implementation dependent.
> **No guarantees on range or value are made**.
> ...
> `void alGenBuffers (ALsizei n, ALuint *bufferNames);`
> `void alGenSources (ALsizei n, ALuint *sourceNames);`

From the other side, if you don't care about other OpenAL implementations, [OpenAL soft](https://openal-soft.org) (as for 1.17) internally returns values starting from `1`, though this should be considered as implementation detail:

```
AL_API ALvoid AL_APIENTRY alGenSources(ALsizei n, ALuint *sources)
{
        ...
        err = NewThunkEntry(&source->id);
        ...
        sources[cur] = source->id;
}

ALenum NewThunkEntry(ALuint *index)
{
    ...
    *index = i+1;
    return AL_NO_ERROR;
}
```